# If an IP is not listening on HTTP (isn't a server) or is offline, does the GET request parameters still get sent over the wire to them?

Tags: http

Let's say I know of an IP for example 1.2.3.4

and 1.2.3.4 isn't a webserver (so not listening for http requests) or 1.2.3.4 might be offline (powerouttage).

If in my browser, I typed:
http://1.2.3.4?message=Love&subject=You
and then I hit enter.

Does/Do the parameter(s) in this example message and subject still get sent over the wires and try it reach the IP 1.2.3.4?
Of course I won't get a response but I only want to know if it's still sent over wires.

I tried using some packet viewer on chrome and it shows the GET request going out with parameters..but I want to know if the request with parameters actually gets to travel over the wire and make the usual hops to reach the IP (even though it is dropped once it reaches the IP because IP isn't listening).

Comment: What exactly is a "packet viewer on Chrome"?

Comment: I installed something that captured all the things that gets sent or received...not sure what it was called let me check

Comment: I forgot what it was called now but it showed the GET request, but then I removed that extension
But then I installed Fiddler (Everywhere) and it also captured the GET request which showed parameters.

Comment: It's pretty important *where* exactly you capture those packets. The browser may hand the request to the OS' networking stack which will then try to deliver it; depending on where in the chain you look, it may seem like it's been "handed over to the next handler in the stack", but it didn't actually leave your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical browser will send entire URI over the wire, that's how HTTP is supposed to work. Regardless of whether the destination is a webserver or not (there's no way to know that a priori anyway). However the server should at least accept TCP connections for the consecutive write to happen. Meaning that if the server is offline then the connection won't be established and so no further network activity will happen.

Note that by "server" here I don't mean the final server in the proxy chain, but the one closest to you, the client. And so in the following chain: browser -> Proxy1 -> WebServer, your data will go over the network as long as Proxy1 is up, regardless of the state of the WebServer.

Whether the entire request goes through every potential intermediate machine and in an unmodified state fully depends on those machines and it is impossible to know that. But a typical proxy will try to pass the request unchanged or maybe slightly modified (it may add some headers but URI is typically left as it is).

That's why responses are so important. The only case when you can be sure that your request reached the destination is when the destination sends back a response that reaches you. It is analogous to classical mailing. You write a letter and pass it to a post office. There's no way for you to know whether the letter reaches the destination or not. Actually there's no way to know where it is at a given moment. Unless your recipient sends you back a response.

Comment: Okay then my next question is if the IP is an IP of a users router that is powererd On but isn't a webserver at all....but they're on and can be ping-ed.
and the chain was my_browser -> Proxy 1 -> Proxy 2 -> IP
does my request get to travel over the wires the whole proxy path?

Comment: @TinTran its impossible to know that. Fully depends on those proxies.

Comment: really? okay so I just want to know if it gets to travel some path, doesn't have to be that exact path of the ping-ed. if an IP is there when pinged then does the request get sent over some path to final IP?

Comment: @TinTran the only thing that you can be sure of is that your data left your machine and went over the wire. You can't even be sure that it reached Proxy1. But even if it did, the Proxy1 may or may not simply silently block you. There's no way to know that, it is closely related to the two generals problem. That's why servers respond with... responses. XD This is the real notification that your request reached the destination. Unless of course you have full control over the network (which I assume is not the case).

Comment: Okay but in a typical (well not typical but for the general case for me where IP can be pinged because they're online and browsing the web for example) situation where all the intermediate possible proxies are up, can I assume that my GET request with parameters got to their IP and it was dropped because they're not listening for http requests so I don't expect a response. I don't need to know for sure I just want to know if that generally that is what happens.

Comment: I like your post office example.... I just want to know that if everything goes well the letter gets to destination address (don't care if it gets thrown in trash or not by receiver) as long as the letter gets delivered along some path to that house so if someone were to observe/listen at proxy locations they can see my mail/requests.... Not to know for sure because I don't get a reply from receiver but can I assume that the proxies made effort to try to send it to receiver?

Comment: @TinTran there can be many reasons why your request got dropped somewhere before reaching the destination. IP blacklisting comes to my mind as the most common situation. I can't really answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The request would go over a *TCP connection*, which must first be established via 3-way handshake. If the remote server is offline and does not respond to the first `SYN` TCP handshake request, then that should be that and nothing else should be sent.

If of course you still have an active TCP connection to the server from a previous request, then that handshake doesn't need to be repeated and your computer will assume the previously negotiated connection is still good, and directly send the HTTP request over the wire. It'll only notice that the connection has dropped when it doesn't get a reply to that request after a while.

You can of course get into more complex territory if any proxies or gateways are involved which may try to handle the request as middleman, in which case the request may go to one of those, but won't reach the final destination.